# Insert hyperlink to code generated value in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create a hyperlink in R Markdown that is linked to an address generated by an R code in the chunk above. But this is not working.
Example:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

 
```{r}
x="www.google.com"
```
this is `r x`

[site](`r x`)
````

output: this is `r x` generates the true value which is [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

but the link to the word site includes the path to folder where the .rmd file is located followed by [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

any thoughts on what I can do different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not sure why it works this way, but you need http:// before (or https:// if it's a secure site).

````
```{r}
x = "http://www.google.com"
```
````

Then your method should work or you can use the standard html href

```
[site](`r x`)

<a href=`r x`>site<a>
```